capturing data to a syslog server over a TAP port
Monitoring an air gapped network and need to capture syslog data on the airgapped network and send to my collector over a TAP - is anyone doing this and if so can you share your configuration so that I can review it and see if it fits our scenario?
The only approach that we can come up with is to us tcpdump and replay the packets - this isn't very efficient; we want to see if we can capture the syslog data sent from sensors to the air gapped network's log collector and ingest them over the tap by our log collector.
